# Conditional formatting with VBA for multiple conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with a number of sheets used by users. They are asked to input information in some of the sheets and the first Sheet is a summary of results. There are four conditions, if selected, lead to a pens down scenario where no further work needs to take place. Let's say if, Cells A1, B1, and C1 = "No", or if Col 1 in Sheet 2 contains "No", no further work needs to be done in Cells D12:K39, or some such range.

I thought running with conditional formatting may work, but the results are not great. Something like: `=$A$1="No"`, and so on for the other conditions, then I colour out the selection range

I'm very new to VBA, but see this as way to get my results. I have no idea how to structure the above condition.

Comment: What code have you written so far to try and do this? Please share any code snippets that would help us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't give up on conditional formatting just yet.

1. Select Cells `D12:K39`
2. Go to *Conditional Formatting* > *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*
3. Enter the formula `=OR(COUNTIF($A$1:$C$1,"No")=3,COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A:$A,"No")>0)`
4. Change the formatting as needed

[image]

Comment: Alternatively, select ONE of the cells you want to apply the format to; enter a conditional format formula that works for that one cell, absoluting rows and columns as needed (`$`) - create the rule, then in the "applies to" textbox pick D12:K39 to extend the conditional logic to the whole desired range.

Comment: thanks, conditional formatting was my go to; the problem I have is I have other conditional formatting already taking place, and the colour schemes overlap

Comment: Maybe you can [manage conditional formatting rule precedence](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-conditional-formatting-rule-precedence-e09711a3-48df-4bcb-b82c-9d8b8b22463d)?

Comment: @premiumcopypaper order your rules accordingly (higher priority rules first); check the "stop if true" box